# Searching for a string, adding a string, and removing a string in a file

Tags: java, file, filewriter

I have a file with a list of objects of people. a string First name, string last name, & int id. I need a method to sort it, a method to add a name to the array, a method to remove names from the list, and a method to search the list. 
update: these methods work but i need to use these methods in a switch statement on my main method in a different class. Do i need to rename them or how do i do it?
    public class aList {
    String fn;
    String ln;
    int id;
    static Person p;

```
List<Person> myList = new ArrayList<Person>();

public aList(File fi) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(fi);
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        fn = sc.next();
        ln = sc.next();
        id = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(fn + " " + ln + " " + id);
        p = new Person(fn, ln, id);
        myList.add(p);
    }
    System.out.println("After reading in the file \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(myList.get(i).toString() + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
    sc.close();

}

public void sortIt() {
    Collections.sort(myList);
    System.out.println(" After sorting \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(myList.get(i).toString() + "\t");
    }
}

public void add(String name) {
    myList.add(new Person(name, name, id));
}

public void remove(String name) {
    for (Person p : myList) {
        if (p.getName().equals(name)) {
            myList.remove(p);
        } else
            System.out.print("Not a valid name");
    }
}

public Person find(String name) {
    for (Person p : myList) {
        if (p.getName().equals(name)) {
            return p;

        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

}

Comment: Please be more specific than “it wouldn’t work.”  What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some candidates for add, remove, find:

```
    public void add(String name){
        myList.add(new Person(name));//assumes the constructor takes in name param
    }
    public void remove(String name){
        for (Person p : myList){
           if (p.getName().equals(name)){//assumes person class has a getName() method
               myList.remove(p);
           }
    }
    public void find(String name){
        for (Person p : myList){
           if (p.getName().equals(name)){//assumes person class has a getName() method
               return p;
           }
    }
```

Re sorting, though, I'd have to know what you're sorting based on - is it lexicographic order?